# Where is location of users via Nautilus

Tags: nautilus, users

When I browse files, I like to use Nautilus...especially when in root. Where do I locate the users of the computer via Nautilus?

Comment: What do you mean, locate users?

Comment: A user's home directory is at `/home/<username`. If you want a list of all users on a system, you can't use nautilus for that - you'll need to open the list of all users at `/etc/passwd`

Comment: By "locate users", I mean where do I find the file/directory that lists them. Kind of like on Windows where you can go C:\Users and it will list everyone on the computer.

Comment: To make a long story short, there was a virus on my computer that, every time I clicked on a folder, it would get deleted. After powering off my computer and powering back on, I am only able to boot using a LiveCD. I am trying to get into my user that I stored all my backups in so I can restore my computer and get back lost information......but can't find the user.

Comment: A user's home directory is at /home/<username>, unless root user decided to put a user some other place.  the 9th column in /etc/passwd will tell you where a "user's" home is.  A tricky user could exist, without a home directory.  Virus eh? I'd love to see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user account information is stored in [`/etc/passwd`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man5/passwd.5.html) in a default Ubuntu installation. Password information is in [`/etc/shadow`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man5/shadow.5.html) and group information in [`/etc/group`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man5/group.5.html).

## None of these files should be edited by hand.